# Conditional Sum up in SQL Server Reporting Service

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I only have two records in the table. One is `Fields!Type.Value="**Buy**"`, and `Fields!Type.Value=59`. The other one is `Fields!Type.Value="**Sell**"`, and `Fields!Type.Value=59`. Here I want to do conditional sum up (if it is "Sell", subtract from the total), so the result I expect is 0. I used the following formula, but it sums up the two rows, and I got 118. Why?

```
=sum(iif(Fields!Type.Value="Sell",-1*Fields!Shares.Value,Fields!Shares.Value))
```

Comment: can you show some sample data with your question?

Answer (score 1):

**Revised answer**

My preferred option would be to modify the data source on the SQL side, so we can have a new field with the sign set correctly for each row.

Add this as a new column in your select statement:

```
CASE WHEN Type = 'Sell' THEN - 1 * share ELSE share END as ValueToSumInReport
```

Note you will need to modify to use your actual field names. Add the field to your report as

```
=SUM(Fields!ValueToSumInReport.Value)
```

Comment: Actually there are only two values for Type, one is "Sell", and one is "Buy". There are no two stars. I made it in bold when typing the question, and that is why you saw "**Sell**".

Comment: @Cathy, Did my revised answer with the case statement help you?